# How to retrieve data from radio button in jsp and put it in session

Tags: javascript, jsp

I read some answers related to my topic but when I try to run the code it shows an exception...

The answer I tried

```
String answer1=request.getSession().getAttribute("my1").toString();
```

The Exception I got

> HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /First.jsp
>   at line 59
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /First.jsp at line 59

```
58: <%
59: String answer1=request.getSession().getAttribute("my1").toString();
60:             
61:             
62: %>
```

Comment: Please make your code more readable using the code sample function in the editor {}

Comment: I don´t know what exactly you want to do. The jsp code is executed on server side. To get the data of a radio button, you need to do that on client side.